# How to extract list of lists in python django request.POST

Tags: python, ajax, django, post

I have posted data from ajax, data include csrfmiddlewaretoken(string), rcount(int) and list of prices. POSTED Data to Django view looks like this.

```
<QueryDict: {u'prices[2][]': [u'2128', u'5', u'06/09/2016', u'12:00 AM'], u'prices[0][]': [u'2147', u'5', u'06/09/2016', u'12:00 AM'], u'rcount': [u'59'], u'prices[1][]': [u'2108', u'5', u'06/09/2016', u'12:00 AM'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'55qQByfBUxgII2nLJCkFZHHaJjJCF70p']}>
```

Now when I access rcount using following syntax, it works fine.

```
request.POST.get(rcount)
```

But when I try to access prices variable, It failed to get values.

```
request.POST.get(prices)
or
request.POST.getlist(prices)
```

This code is used to post data from HTML to Django View.

```
var records = []

records.push([2128, 5, '06/09/2016', '12:00 AM']);
records.push([2147, 5, '06/09/2016', '12:00 AM']);
records.push([2108, 5, '06/09/2016', '12:00 AM']);

var postData = {prices: records, rcount:59, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"};
var posting = $.post('/myview/setprices/', postData);
```

How Can I access prices list?

From the answer of Rajesh Yogeshwar, I have used stringify and change postData as

```
var postData = {prices: JSON.stringify((records), rcount:59, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"};
var posting = $.post('/myview/setprices/', postData);
```

And Now Prices are found as JSON value in request.POST and can be converted to python list using following syntax.

```
prices = request.POST.get('prices')
if prices:
    prices = json.loads(prices)
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Looking at the data it seems, you are creating it somewhere in your js and posting it. So why dont you try to jsonify it by using JSON.stringify()

Comment: On second thought you can better format your data I mean rather than pushing items to record as list you can use dictionaries and then do JSON.stringify on your records object.

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: Check out the answer I have posted it might solve your problem, I have named keys as key1, key2 you can replace them with something meaningful. Let me know if you face further issues in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In continuation to my comments on your original question, you can format data in such a way

```
var records = new Array();

records.push({'key1': 2128, 'key2': 5, 'key3': '06/09/2016', 'key4': '12:00 AM'})
```

You can push N number of records into your **records** array like this.

After that, you can replace this line

```
var postData = {prices: records, rcount:59, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"};
```

with this

```
var postData = {prices: JSON.stringify(records), rcount:59, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"};
```

In your views then, you can simply do

```
prices = request.POST.get('prices', None)
if prices:
    prices = json.loads(prices)
```

So now prices is list of dictionaries and you can do whatever you want it

Comment: stringify is adding extra empty dicts in records list.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because there is no `'prices'` key in the dictionary you provided.
There are instead keys `'prices[2][]'`, `'prices[0][]'` and `'prices[1][]'`. These are ordinary strings.

You should check the way that this data get posted.